# mongoose findOne() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

gooModel.js

//user model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const GooSchema = new Schema(
    {
        goo_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
    },
    { collection: 'goo_collection' }
);


module.exports = Goo = mongoose.model(
    'goo',
    GooSchema
);
```

auth_controller.js

//new user

```
    const NewGoo = new Goo({
        goo_id,
    })
```

//function

```
await NewGoo.findOne({ goo })}
```

I am getting findOne() is not a function error. I have no idea where I have made a mistake. It creates the collection on my mongo atlas DB (but it is empty). I have exactly the same model in the different route that works. I am super clueless right now.

Comment: Can you show us how you import `Goo`?

Comment: `const Goo = require('../../models/gooModel');`.   and `console.log(Goo)` returns `Model {goo_collection}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call `findOne` on the model itself, not on the instance/document which `NewGoo` refers to. So try changing it to:

```
await Goo.findOne({ goo })}
```

Comment: omg. It was just right there.... I looked it up for like 15 times and couldn't spot the error!

Comment: Been there my friend, it happens to all of us :) Please, don't forget to accept my answer, thank you!